# Replace arabic characters in JSON file

Tags: python, json, arabic

I want to delete all Arabic characters in this JSON file:

**comments.json**

```json
{
    "comments": [
        "Dunkin Doughnuts inside a bowling center? That's really amazing ",
        "Best localtion",
        "Dunkin' Donuts☕️",
        "Good",
        "Tasty",
        "Donuts",
        "Dunkin' Donuts DD The well-known does not know My order was espresso The branch is located inside the bowling alley But the fault of this branch is that one employee is late In orders and their donuts are second to none  دانكن دونتس DD المعروف لا يعرف طلبي كان اسبريسو الفرع موجود داخل صالة البولينق لكن عيب هالفرع ان موظف واحد ويتأخر في الطلبات والدونات عندهم لا يعلى عليها ",
        "Dunkin 'Donuts is a global coffee chain, which has been in operation since 1950 in Quincy, USA. William Rosberg opened a restaurant selling coffee and donuts in 1948, in Quincy (Massachusetts) and named it The Open Kettle, meaning an open pan. After the project was a success, and after a while he opened the first coffee and donut shop in 1950, he was known as Dunkin Donuts and it is still standing to this day. In 1954 Rosenburg opened five more Dunkin 'Donuts stores with some other products added to the order list. In 1980, Dunkin Donuts bought Baskin Robbins and some other companies to establish a coalition company called the Dunkin 'Brands brand, and then it spread all over the world. دانكن دونتس (بالإنجليزية: Dunkin' Donuts)سلسلة محلات قهوة عالمية، بدأت منذ 1950 في كوينسي بالولايات المتحدة الأمريكية. قام ويليام روزبيرغ بإفتتاح مطعم يبيع القهوة والدونات عام 1948، في كوينسي (ماساتشوستس) وأطلق عليه اسم The Open Kettle أي المقلاة المفتوحة. بعد أن لاقى المشروع النجاح، وبعد فترة قام بافتتاح أول محل للقهوة والدونت عام 1950، عرف باسم دانكن دونتس حيث ما زال قائما حتى يومنا هذا. وفي 1954 افتتح روزنبورق خمسة فروع أخرى من محلات دانكن دونتس مع اضافة بعض المنتجات الأخرى إلى قائمة الطلبات. في 1980 اشترت شركة دانكن دونتس باسكن روبنز وبعض الشركات الأخرى لتأسيس شركه تحالفيه تسمى علامة دانكن Dunkin' Brands وانتشرت بعدها في جميع أنحاء العالم.",
        "A solution is not alive حلا ولا احلي",
        "excellent ممتاز",
        "How many number arrived home? كم رقم توصل للبيت؟",
        "Dunkin is inside the bowling alley دانكن داخل صالة البولنج",
        "What it does ماعليه",
        "A solution is not alive حلا ولا احلي",
        "I'm a Dunkin fan انا من عشاق دنكن"
    ]
}
```

I'm trying to delete it with the code below and I want to print it without the Arabic characters. `deleted_chars` has all the letters that I'm trying to delete.

```py
import json

comments = []
comments_after_deletion = {'comments': []}
deleted_char_arr = "دجحخهعغفقثصضطكمنتالبيسشظزوةىلارؤءئذ؛×÷‘إلإًٌَُّ،ـألأٍِ؟آلآْ"

with open("reviews V1.0.json", 'r', encoding="utf-8") as jsn:
    coms = json.load(jsn)

    for comment in coms["comments"]:
        for letter in comment:
            for deleted_char in deleted_char_arr:
                if letter == deleted_char:
                    comment.replace(letter, '')
        comments_after_deletion['comments'].append(comment)
    with open("comments after deletion.json", 'w', encoding="utf-8") as f:
        json.dump(comments_after_deletion, f, ensure_ascii=False, indent=4)
```

This is the new JSON file that I got:

**comments after deletion.json**

```json
{
    "comments": [
        "Dunkin Doughnuts inside a bowling center? That's really amazing ",
        "Best localtion",
        "Dunkin' Donuts☕️",
        "Good",
        "Tasty",
        "Donuts",
        "Dunkin' Donuts DD The well-known does not know My order was espresso The branch is located inside the bowling alley But the fault of this branch is that one employee is late In orders and their donuts are second to none  دانكن دونتس DD المعروف لا يعرف طلبي كان اسبريسو الفرع موجود داخل صالة البولينق لكن عيب هالفرع ان موظف واحد ويتأخر في الطلبات والدونات عندهم لا يعلى عليها ",
        "Dunkin 'Donuts is a global coffee chain, which has been in operation since 1950 in Quincy, USA. William Rosberg opened a restaurant selling coffee and donuts in 1948, in Quincy (Massachusetts) and named it The Open Kettle, meaning an open pan. After the project was a success, and after a while he opened the first coffee and donut shop in 1950, he was known as Dunkin Donuts and it is still standing to this day. In 1954 Rosenburg opened five more Dunkin 'Donuts stores with some other products added to the order list. In 1980, Dunkin Donuts bought Baskin Robbins and some other companies to establish a coalition company called the Dunkin 'Brands brand, and then it spread all over the world. دانكن دونتس (بالإنجليزية: Dunkin' Donuts)سلسلة محلات قهوة عالمية، بدأت منذ 1950 في كوينسي بالولايات المتحدة الأمريكية. قام ويليام روزبيرغ بإفتتاح مطعم يبيع القهوة والدونات عام 1948، في كوينسي (ماساتشوستس) وأطلق عليه اسم The Open Kettle أي المقلاة المفتوحة. بعد أن لاقى المشروع النجاح، وبعد فترة قام بافتتاح أول محل للقهوة والدونت عام 1950، عرف باسم دانكن دونتس حيث ما زال قائما حتى يومنا هذا. وفي 1954 افتتح روزنبورق خمسة فروع أخرى من محلات دانكن دونتس مع اضافة بعض المنتجات الأخرى إلى قائمة الطلبات. في 1980 اشترت شركة دانكن دونتس باسكن روبنز وبعض الشركات الأخرى لتأسيس شركه تحالفيه تسمى علامة دانكن Dunkin' Brands وانتشرت بعدها في جميع أنحاء العالم.",
        "A solution is not alive حلا ولا احلي",
        "excellent ممتاز",
        "How many number arrived home? كم رقم توصل للبيت؟",
        "Dunkin is inside the bowling alley دانكن داخل صالة البولنج",
        "What it does ماعليه",
        "A solution is not alive حلا ولا احلي",
        "I'm a Dunkin fan انا من عشاق دنكن"
    ]
}
```

It doesn't work why is that does anyone know how to solve it?

Comment: You aren't storing the result of running `comment.replace(letter, '')` anywhere.

Answer (score 2):

The smallest change is to change the line

```
comment.replace(letter, '')
```

to

```
comment = comment.replace(letter, '')
```

However, this is still quite inefficient. Consider deleting the entire set of unwanted characters at once.

Put this just once at the top of your code:

```
translation_table = str.maketrans('', '', deleted_char_arr)
```

...and later you can run:

```
comment = comment.translate(translation_table)
```

...to perform all the deletions at once.

---

See a working example at https://replit.com/@CharlesDuffy2/KindheartedRareBrowsers#main.py; to reproduce it here:

```
import json

comments = []
c_a_d = {'comments': []} # comments_after_deletion, shortened
deleted_char_arr = "دجحخهعغفقثصضطكمنتالبيسشظزوةىلارؤءئذ؛×÷‘إلإًٌَُّ،ـألأٍِ؟آلآْ"
translation_table = str.maketrans('', '', deleted_char_arr)

with open("reviews V1.0.json", 'r', encoding="utf-8") as jsn:
    coms = json.load(jsn)
    for comment in coms["comments"]:
        c_a_d['comments'].append(comment.translate(translation_table))

with open("comments after deletion.json", 'w', encoding="utf-8") as f:
    json.dump(c_a_d, f, ensure_ascii=False, indent=4)
```

Comment: Very glad to hear! To mark your question solved, click the checkbox next to the answer.